# In x86, how to get character out of string stored inside memory

Tags: x86

I want to pick out certain character out of a string stored in memory, but don't know how

```
str    db "hello",0
mov    rdi,str
call   puts
```

when I do this I get the output hello, but I want to know how to get the first character out. For example how do I move the first character h saved in some register?

Answer (score 1):

```
mov  al, byte ptr [rdi]
```

will move one byte from the address pointed at by rdi into the al register (bottom 8 bits of rax)